# How do I add a new property to the node in AgensGraph?

Tags: properties, set, cypher, agens-graph

I want to add a new property to the node using SET clause. But an error is occurred and query is not executed.

1) 1st command and error message :

```
MATCH (j {name:'Jack'}) SET j.hobby = 'Playing the guitar';

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: match (j {name:'Jack'}) SET j.hobby = 'Playing the guitar';
                                              ^
DETAIL:  Token "Playing" is invalid. 
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: Playing...
```

2) 2nd command and error message :

```
MATCH (j {name:'Jack'}) SET j.hobby = "Playing the guitar";

ERROR:  column "Playing the guitar" does not exist
LINE 1: match (j {name:'Jack'}) SET j.hobby = "Playing the guitar";
```

To add a new property to the node, I wrote query like *1)*. I replaced it with double quotation marks like *2)*, because an error occurred in the single quotation marks. But, *2)* query also causes an error.

How can I add a new property to the node?

Comment: How are you executing this query? The `json` type and the related error messages are a bit suspicious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AgensGraph supports properties on nodes and relationships by using `jsonb` type. So, if you want to add a string value as a property, the value must be a valid JSON string like `'"Playing the guitar"'`. It is somewhat inconvenient to write such queries, but that's how it currently works.